# Grafana for a variable, get values from multiple labels for one metric

Tags: amazon-rds, grafana, grafana-variable

I hope you're having a nice day.

To create a variable in Grafana for a dashboard I need to get values from multiple labels from a metric :

**dbinstance_identifier** & **dbcluster_identifier**

To get the values in my variable i use the function "label_values()", but i can only put 1 label in that function :

**label_values(XXXXXXXX, dbinstance_identifier)**

I would want something like :

**label_values(XXXXXXXX, dbinstance_identifier | dbcluster_identifier)** but it returns a parse error...

What is the best solution ?

Yours sincerely,

Arthur

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using `query_result` and `regex`:

```
query_result(XXXXXXXX{})

/.*_identifier="([^"]*).*/
```